# And Operator's Inconsistency

Tags: python, conditional-statements, operators

The following code runs code if these conditions are met:

- User clicks on a surface called `box`
- the `box` must be moving in **at least** one direction

```
if ((boxLeft < pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] < boxLeft + BOX_SIZE) and (boxTop < pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] < boxTop + BOX_SIZE)) and ((dx != 0) and (dy != 0)):
```

This does not happen. Instead, the code only runs if the box is moving in **both** directions (if both do **not** dx and dy == 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to do `((dx != 0) or (dy != 0))` so it can detect when it's just moving in one direction.

Comment: It worked. But why? shouldn't using the `and` operator check if **both** `dx` and `dy` are **not** == 0?

Comment: @DaeshaunKMorrison if it's only moving in one direction, then the other direction has no movement, or 0 movement.